# Pass data to collectionViewCell made lagging scroll, How to make it more smooth? - Found issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

According my question, I have to pass a data to my collection view cell
It made laggy when scroll. It happened because my setup data function, it pass too big of data but I have no idea how to fix it.

My cell class .

```
class VerificationStepCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var stepLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepNoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var iconImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepStatusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepStatusView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonStatus: BaseButton!
    var currentStepType: VerifyAccountStepType?
    var currentStatus: UserLevelInfoStatus?
    
    var data: HomeModels.ViewModel.VerifyAccountStepModel? = nil
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        self.stepStatusView.layer.cornerRadius = self.stepStatusView.frame.height / 2
    }
    
    func setupData() {
        guard let data = self.data else { return }
        self.currentStepType = data.stepType
        self.currentStatus = data.stepStatus
        self.stepStatusView.isHidden = data.stepStatus == .notVerify
        self.stepLabel.text = "Step\(data.stepNo)"
        self.stepTitleLabel.text = data.stepTitle
        self.stepNoLabel.text = "\(data.stepNo)"
        self.iconImageView.image = data.stepIconImage
        self.stepDescriptionLabel.text = data.stepDescription
        self.stepStatusLabel.text = "home_unverified_account_\(data.stepStatus.rawValue)_status".localized()
        
        switch data.stepStatus {
        case .approve:
            self.buttonStatus.setIsEnable(false)
            self.buttonStatus.setTitle(data.stepButtonTitle, for: .normal)
            self.stepStatusView.backgroundColor = UIColor.Yellows.brighterYellow
            self.stepStatusLabel.textColor = .black
        case .notVerify:
            self.buttonStatus.setIsEnable(true)
            self.buttonStatus.setTitle(data.stepButtonTitle, for: .normal)
            self.stepStatusLabel.textColor = .white
        case .reject:
            self.buttonStatus.setIsEnable(true)
            self.buttonStatus.setTitle("แก้ไข", for: .normal)
            self.stepStatusView.backgroundColor = UIColor.Reds.loss
            self.stepStatusLabel.textColor = .white
        case .pending:
            self.buttonStatus.setIsEnable(false)
            self.buttonStatus.setTitle(data.stepButtonTitle, for: .normal)
            self.stepStatusView.backgroundColor = UIColor.Oranges.deepOrange
            self.stepStatusLabel.textColor = .white
        }
    }
}
```

I know my data is too big but It have to, Has anyone ever face with this problem?
Thank you

**Update solution**
It found my problem already, It cause from my localized text function.
After I removed it everything working fine!~

Comment: When is called `setupData()`? How is passed `data`? Is there more images than `stepIconImage`? Is it from the web? Is it not loaded with `Data(contentsOf:)`? Show `cellForItemAt`

Comment: @Larme I set data on cellForItemAt function and call setupData() after set it and data I just mock it not call from api.. Sorry, I updated my question.

Comment: You code shouldn't "slow" that that much. You data isn't big.  Maybe if `data.stepIconImage` is really heavy, like a 4k*4k px image to show in a 20*20 pts UIImageView, it might slow down... But I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @Larme I also try to remove that part, but it still lag. ( my icon it only 36*36 )

Comment: @Larme For more information, My collection view is in TableViewCell, That is cause of issue ?

Comment: It's simple. If you don't call `setUpData()`, or call `return` directly, is it slow? "My collection view is in TableViewCell" yes, it could be. What's the code of `cellForRowAt:` and `cellForItemAt` in TableView/CollectionView ?

Comment: My tableview pass array of item to cell ( collectionview ) and I pass data to render each cell of collectionviewcell with function `cellForItemAt`

Comment: @Larme If I don't call it, I will not lag anymore.

Comment: @Larme for more information, It lag only first time that I scroll but after that it not lag anymore.